# Como alterar letra driver em tempo de execução no delphi

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, microsoft-access

Amigos, resolvi simplificar o uso de um sistema em `Delphi`, usando o `banco de dados` e o executável disponível em um arquivo em `pen drive`. 
Com isso, tenho minhas tabelas em `Access`, e dispostas em um `DataModule` com `ADOQuery`, com conexão alinhadas com o drive `E:`, por exemplo.

Ocorre que quando conecto o drive em outro pc nem sempre reconhecerá esse pen drive como `"E:"`, podendo definir automaticamente outra letra. Sei como alterar a letra pelo windows mas se tiver restrição para acesso desse recurso, fica complicado.

Assim, pretendo inserir um `Combobox` que permita ajustar meu programa com a letra que ficar indicada no pc de uso, ou mesmo se programar o reconhecimento e ajuste automáticamente tão logo inicializado.

Conto com a ajuda dos colegas, caso isso seja possível. Grato.

Comment: Algum problema em utilizar o caminho que o executável está? Por exemplo usando `Paramstr(0)` e `ExtractFileDrie`? (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ExtractFileDrive)

Answer (score 3):

Por que ao invés de usar o caminho absoluto (`e:\app\base\arquivo.mdb`), você não usa caminho relativo para acessar seu banco (`base\arquivo.mdb`)? Isso resolveria seu problema.

Se mesmo assim você ainda quiser saber em drive seu pendrive está, você pode usar o comando `ExtractFileDrive(ParamStr(0))`.

Comment: Valmir, grato pela ajuda. Como comentei, minha tabela está conectada com um ADOQuery, que define o caminho (path) incluindo a letra de drive.

Comment: Como faria esse "caminho relativo" sem usar a letra do drive? Não leve a mal, mas sou autodidata em programação e se puder esclarecer escrevendo o codigo, pode me ajudar mais.

Comment: Mas você não tem acesso a configuração desse `ADOQuery`? Como está na reposta, você pode omitir a letra do drive e colocar no caminho as subpastas até o arquivo `MSAccess`.